# Richardson's Extrapolation

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, extrapolation

Use Richardson's extrapolation to find a 3 point 2nd order approximation of f  '(x).

I'm not sure how to go about to start this, i'm not the best when using richardson's extrapolation.

Comment: it justs asks to use richardson's extrapolation to find 3pt formula with O(H^2) error.

Comment: sorry, of f'(x)

Comment: yes, f(x)= f'(x)

Comment: derivative of f(x)...there was no f(x) specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the two-point forward difference formula, we have:

$$\tag 1 f'(x) \approx \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Using Richardson's, we replace $h$ by $\dfrac{h}{2}$ in $(1)$, yielding:

$$\tag 2 f'(x) \approx 2\dfrac{f(x+h/2)-f(x)}{h}$$

Subtracting $2 \times (2)$ from $(1)$ (this is to get the Richardson form) yields:

$$f'(x) \approx \frac{- f(x+h) + 4 f(x+h/2)- 3f(x) }{h} $$

This is a $3-$point, $2^{nd}$ order approximation.

Comment: Ooh, you were busy today! +1